# How can I find periodically appearing NA values in an 3D array (along dimension time) with R

Tags: arrays, r, time-series, na

I have a time series (monthly values over several years) of spatial data (originally ncdf) in an array. If there are more than 2 consecutive e.g. januaries with NA, I want to ban this pixel (now cell in the matrix of one time step) completely from further studies by putting it to NA in all time steps.

As far as I am concerned, "time.series" is only valid for vectors or matrices (maximum of two-dimensions).

One workaround I can see (but also not manage to implement) is:
Resorting the array in a way that the order isn't purely chronological anymore but sorted by month (jan 2001, jan2002, jan 2003, feb 2001, feb 2002, feb 2003,...) would already help a lot. But it would leave the case that pixels get NA if eg. jan 2002, jan 2003 and feb 2001 are NA.

Any help would be really appreciated. Please ask if my question is unclear - it's my first one - I tried my best.

edit: 
My actual dataset is a global satellite based radiation dataset. Due to eg periodically appearing clouds (during rainseason in the same month every year) those pixel should not be considered any further. I also have some other criteria which eliminates pixel. Only that one criteria is missing.

```
# create any array with scattered NAs 
set.seed (10)
array <- replicate(48, replicate(10, rnorm(20)))
na_pixels <- array((sample(c(1, NA), size = 7200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.95, 0.05))), dim = c(20,10,48))
    na_array <- array * na_pixels

dimnames(na_array) <- list(NULL, NULL, as.character(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2004-12-01"), "month")))

#I want to test several conditions that would make a pixel not usable for me
#in the end I want to retrieve a mask of usable "pixels".
#what I am doing already is: 
mask <- apply(na_array, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN=function(x){
  #check if more than 10% of a pixel are NA over time
  if (sum(is.na(x)) > (length(x)*0.05)){
    mask_val <- 0
  }
  #check if more than 5 pixel are missing consecutively
  else if (max(with(rle(is.na(a)), lengths[values])) > 5){ 
    mask_val <- 0
  }
  #this is the missing part
   else if (...more than 2 januaries or 2 feburaries or... are NA){#check for periodically appearing NAs
     mask_val <- 0
  }
  else {
    mask_val <- 1
  }
  return(mask_val)
})
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and what the expected output looks like?

Comment: I did now, hope that helps to understand my problem. thanks

Comment: I changed the `dimnames` of `na_array` to "character" otherwise it got converted to numeric. Hope it still matches your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's, probably, more convenient (if the necessary memory exists) to change your 3D array in a 'long' "data.frame":

```
as.data.frame(as.table(na_array))
#     Var1 Var2       Var3        Freq
#1       A    A 2001-01-01  0.01874617
#2       B    A 2001-01-01 -0.18425254
#3       C    A 2001-01-01 -1.37133055
#       ...........................
#9598    R    J 2004-12-01          NA
#9599    S    J 2004-12-01 -1.11411416
#9600    T    J 2004-12-01  0.01435433
```

Instead of relying on `as.table` and `as.data.frame` coercions, it could be done manually and more efficiently:

```
dat = data.frame(i = rep_len(seq_len(dim(na_array)[1]), prod(dim(na_array))), 
                 j = rep_len(rep(seq_len(dim(na_array)[2]), each = dim(na_array)[1]), prod(dim(na_array))),
                 date = rep(as.Date(dimnames(na_array)[[3]]), each = prod(dim(na_array)[1:2])) , 
                 month = rep(format(as.Date(dimnames(na_array)[[3]]), "%b"), each = prod(dim(na_array)[1:2])), 
                 isNA = c(is.na(na_array)))
dat
#      i j       date month  isNA
#1     1 1 2001-01-01   Jan FALSE
#2     2 1 2001-01-01   Jan FALSE
#3     3 1 2001-01-01   Jan FALSE
#4     4 1 2001-01-01   Jan  TRUE
#          ..............
#9597 17 10 2004-12-01   Dec FALSE
#9598 18 10 2004-12-01   Dec  TRUE
#9599 19 10 2004-12-01   Dec FALSE
#9600 20 10 2004-12-01   Dec FALSE
```

Where `i`: row in `na_array`, `j`: column in `na_array`, `date`: 3rd dim of `na_array`, `month`: month of the `date` column (as it will be needed later), `isNA`: whether the value of `na_array` is `NA`.

And building the three conditions:

```
cond1 = aggregate(isNA ~ i + j, dat, function(x) sum(x) > (dim(na_array)[3] * 0.05))
```

(A more efficient way to create `cond1` is `rowSums(is.na(na_array), dims = 2) > (dim(na_array)[3] * 0.05)`).

```
cond2 = aggregate(isNA ~ i + j, dat, function(x) any(with(rle(x), lengths[values]) > 5))
```

And to compute `cond3`, first find the number of missing values per "month" per each 'cell' (i.e. [i, j]) ("month" is a variable created/extracted from the `dimnames(na_array)[[3]]` when creating the 'long' "data.frame" `dat` in the beginning):

```
NA_per_month = aggregate(isNA ~ i + j + month, dat, function(x) sum(x))
```

Having the number of `NA`s per "month" for each [i, j], we build `cond3` by checking if each [i, j] contains `any` "month" with more than 2 `NA`s:

```
cond3 = aggregate(isNA ~ i + j, NA_per_month, function(x) any(x > 2))
```

*(It's trivial to replace `aggregate` in the above 'group-by' operations by any other available)*.

Perhaps we could avoid creating a 'long' "data.frame" and operate on `na_array` directly. For example, calculating `cond1` with the `rowSums` version is much more efficient and straightforward. `cond2`, too, could be saved by an `apply` on `na_array`. But `cond3` becomes much more straightforward with a 'long' "data.frame" rather than with a 3D array. So, accounting for efficiency, it's always better to try working with the structure present in the data and if it gets cumbersome enough, then we should probably change the structure of our data once and calculate anything in another scaffold than previously.

To get the final result, allocate a "matrix" of appropriate size:

```
ans = matrix(NA, dim(na_array)[1], dim(na_array)[2])
```

and fill in after `OR`ing the conditions:

```
ans[cbind(cond1$i, cond1$j)] = cond1$isNA | cond2$isNA | cond3$isNA

ans
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [8,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[10,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[11,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[12,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[13,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[14,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[15,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[16,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[17,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[18,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[19,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[20,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your answer. Obviouslyit is ok to change the Dates to "characters". It is working now. Still I would really like to understand "cond3" better. I don't really get how the consecutive part is taken into account here. I guess I can't wrap my head around the "i+j+month"-part. If you could elaborate on that cond2-part a bit, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Geoline : I think it's a bit cleaner with the two steps after the edit. Generally, the "formula" interface of `aggregate` reads like `aggregate(value ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3 + ..., from_which_data, with_what_function)`. Instead of `aggregate` you could try `tapply`, `lapply(split(x, by), function)`, or packages built with such operations in view.

Comment: @alixis_laz: thanks for the clearyfication and please tell me if I am wrong, BUT: in the "NA_per_month" for each pixel/cell it is only stored how many values are missing. The information of the order is lost, am I right? eg for january: 2001 = NA, 2002 = 4, 2003 = NA, 2004 = NA. cond3 would be met. right? I only want to mask pixel with 3 consecutive missing values. so 2001 = NA, 2002 = NA, 2003= NA, 2004 = 5 should fulfil the conditions but the first one shouldn't.

Comment: @Geoline : Oh, you mean the check should be ".. if more than two _consecutive_ januaries etc are `NA`.."? Sorry, I totally missed that. Then, unless I'm missing something, `NA_per_month` shoule be built like `aggregate(isNA ~ i + j + month, dat, function(x) with(rle(x), any(lengths[values] > 2)))`? (Note that, when creating `dat`, the order along the date (i.e. the 3rd dimension) is kept).

Comment: I wanted to comment, but with code it was too long so I posted it as an answer. Hope that was right.

Answer (score 0):

@ alexis_laz: Yes, this works now. Unfortunately I realised that the `ans[cbind(cond1$i, cond1$j)] = cond1$isNA | cond2$isNA | cond3$isNA` is not working. I get the error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. I think it only takes the cond1 for replacement. (I am sorry for my example dataset which gives 'FALSE' in all cases for cond2 and cond3 but still, it should check the 'OR' in the code.Even though the result will look the same like cond1) I came up with the following code, which works but is definately not niceor efficient because I am not too familiar with boolean stuff. Perhaps you could optimize my code or edit your line (as my real dataset is huge, i would be greatful fpr any optimization). In the far end I would need all True conditions (meaning NA) to be 0 and all FALSE conditions to be 1. That's why I already did this in my code here.

```
ans = matrix(NA, dim(na_array)[1], dim(na_array)[2])
cond1_bool <- ans
cond1_bool[cbind(cond1$i, cond1$j)] = cond1$isNA
cond2_bool <- ans
cond2_bool[cbind(cond2$i, cond2$j)] = cond2$isNA
cond3_bool <- ans
cond3_bool[cbind(cond3$i, cond3$j)] = cond3$isNA
ans_bool <- ans
ans_bool[which(cond1_bool == T|cond2_bool == T|cond3_bool == T)] <- 0
ans_bool[which(is.na(ans_bool))] <- 1
```

Comment: I guess it's, actually, a warning rather than en error? (R, generally, warns about non equal length replacement). I assume that in your real data only you get this warning (because with the above data I get no warning)? Do, all of `cond1`, `cond2`, and `cond3` have equal `dim` and have appropriate `names` ("i", "j", and "isNA")? Also, what is the `dim` of your actual array (it might be worth to avoid some `aggregate`-y stuff with something more efficient)?

Comment: Ok, good point. I see, I got something mixed up from line NA_per_month to cond3. As you wrote earlier, I replaced the 'NA_per_month' line. But, if I want to exclude a pixel even if the two consecutive NAs appear during one month, the cond3 has to be 'cond3 = aggregate(isNA ~ i + j, NA_per_month, function(x) any(x > 0))', right? By the way, my real dataframe is 1440x720x96. The 96 is a minimum which will possibly be extended at some later stage of my project. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. For `cond3`, I guess it should be `> 1` ; `> 0` will, also, discard cells with only one `NA` in a month